# Type definition for an object, which takes (self) reference on its values for a type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to define a type for an object, where one keys type takes reference on the values of another key?

Let's say we want to have a type `Configuration` where `languages` can be defined. How can I make sure that the key `defaultLanguage` is one of the languages? The `languages` should act as union type.

It is possible to write..

```
export const languages = ['de-CH', 'en-GB'] as const;
type Language = typeof languages[number];

export const defaultLanguage: Language = 'de-CH';
```

.., but is it also possible to write the type for an object, which represents the same without extract the `languages`?

```
type Configuration = {
  languages: string[],
  defaultLanguage: // A type which takes the values of languages and uses them as an union type here
}
```

Here two simple test cases:

```
const goodConfig: Configuration = {
  languages: ['de-CH', 'en-GB'],
  defaultLanguage: 'de-CH'
}

const badConfig: Configuration = {
  languages: ['de-CH', 'en-GB'],
  defaultLanguage: 'de-DE' // <- type error
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't represent `Configuration` as a *specific* type in TypeScript unless there's some moderately-sized union of possible language [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) you want to select subsets from.  if the `languages` property can really accept any array of *any possible* strings, then a specific `Configuration` type would have to an infinite union of all possibilities, which is not expressible in TypeScript.

--

Instead, you can represent `Configuration<L>` as a [*generic*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type, like this:

```
type Configuration<L extends string> = {
    languages: L[],
    defaultLanguage: L;
}
```

The idea is that `L` here represents a union of possible language string literals for a particular configuration object.  The `languages` property is an array of these, and the `defaultLanguage` property is just one of these.

Conceptually, you'd like to say "a `Configuration` is a `Configuration<L>` object for *some* type `L` I don't know or care about".  This sort of generic type where you only care that the parameter is *some* type is called an [*existential type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types).  Unfortunately, TypeScript does not directly support existential types (although they have been requested, see [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466)).  So there's no easy way to say `type DesiredConfiguration = <∃L>Configuration L` right now.

---

That means in order to use `Configuration<L>`, the `L` type must be specified somehow.  It can be done manually via annotation, but that is annoying:

```
const annoyingConfig: Configuration<'de-CH' | 'en-GB'> = {
    languages: ['de-CH', 'en-GB'],
    defaultLanguage: 'de-CH'
}
```

Blecch.  Instead, we can try to get the compiler to *infer* the `L` when faced with a candidate value of type `Configuration<L>`.  To do this we introduce a generic "do-nothing" or "identity" function which just returns its input at runtime, but the generic function call can be used to make the compiler infer `L`:

```
const asConfiguration = <L extends string>(config: Configuration<L>) => config;

const goodConfig = asConfiguration({
    languages: ['de-CH', 'en-GB'],
    defaultLanguage: 'de-CH'
})
// const goodConfig: Configuration<"de-CH" | "en-GB">
```

Hooray, the inference worked.  Now let's see the bad config error:

```
const badConfig = asConfiguration({
    languages: ['de-CH', 'en-GB'],
    defaultLanguage: 'de-DE' // wait, no error?
});
// const badConfig: Configuration<"de-CH" | "en-GB" | "de-DE">
```

Uh oh, there's no error.  The inference worked *too well*, and now `L` as the union of all three values!

---

Ideally, you want to say something like "when inferring a `Configuration<L>`, use the `languages` property only, and only *check* the `defaultLanguage` property.  We would like the `L` in `defaultLanguage` to be "non-inferential".  This is the subject of a feature request, [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829).  The idea is that we would change `Configuration<L>`'s definition to:

```
type Configuration<L extends string> = {
    languages: L[],
    defaultLanguage: NoInfer<L>;
}
```

for some suitable definition of `NoInfer`.  There's no official version of `NoInfer`, and that GitHub issue is still open.  But the discussion there does give a few suggestions for possible do-it-yourself implementations, such as [this suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731):

```
type NoInfer<T> = T & {}
```

or [this suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546):

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : 1];
```

I usually go with the latter.  If we use it, things behave as desired now.  The `goodConfig` is still good, and now `badConfig` is bad:

```
const badConfig = asConfiguration({
    languages: ['de-CH', 'en-GB'],
    defaultLanguage: 'de-DE' // error!
    // Type '"de-DE"' is not assignable to type '"de-CH" | "en-GB"'
});
// const badConfig: Configuration<"de-CH" | "en-GB">
```

---

This works now.  One drawback to using a generic type instead of a specific type is that now anything in your code which you wanted to depend on `Configuration` must also be generic now.  Rather than spread this `L` parameter all over your code base, you might want to keep it just so that it validates developer specified configuration objects, but widen to a non-constrained version for your own code.

So external-facing code will validate and then make calls to internal-facing code which will not care about that constraint:

```
function externalFacingCode<L extends string>(c: Configuration<L>) {
    internalFacingCode(c);
}

interface InternalConfiguration {
    languages: string[],
    defaultLanguage: string
}

function internalFacingCode(c: InternalConfiguration) {
    c.languages.find(x => x === c.defaultLanguage)!.toUpperCase();
}
```

---

Recap:

- You can't currently represent `Configuration` as a specific type.
- You *can* represent it as a *generic* type, but you need to specify its type parameter.
- It is tedious to do this manually via annotation.
- It is easier to do via helper function but setting up the function is tricky.
- In any case it's more complicated than a specific type so you might want to limit its use to just validation code.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcE8AcFNQHIHsCSA7AZrATgHgCoB8oAvKPqAGSgDeAvgLABQUciqmOBxZA2vgF1+oWAA9wsNABMAzqACGaSKAD8oAAygAXKACMAgNzNmreAGEkmAJYBzAK7Z54K5dwAZEeMmzQM8Nis0Gx5aZlBw0AAbRXt5G1gZHTdeAQAaMIipWAx5O0jwNxi7ONgdZHQsPDdCIyZGJmYAY0s-BTQ0JEhAmwtrGx1ejFsHJxc0XAByLIBaMwAJCdAAH1AJyWmAcQAhCZCaDPDooOL4xNBeKdhZhdTV9e2JtIPQLJy8gqKSnUvrieZ6potcAKGSDYaOZyWUigdyeCTSOR+AJBQgACmafQGliG9ghY3chAAlKRiBicbVAWhWjYkEgpGCbND5KDseDRpZUfsmBEop9TjoLjN5hNbms0Jsdk9uZlsrl8oVjl9VkKFv9CcwQKAMdTafTWf1QAyRpDxgAiFWm5agU33LamwjGJja4EAI3ker6TJZfWNY05zyOsX55x+wtFtse6Wl4Veco+ivi3xmABEAKKLTU4bBIbAAQmemvwMHgE3NVzTpsWVjkHWBzJktjQ8hdkXg4CQEGLqzL10tKxt4u2lbVtU1LuyOfg5U42FAQ1EWg1YGdoDdHpxWJ9eNcPfmfettv3PYrDoaTE18gwEln08qc6sC6XWqBq-dDM3ON9O4tVoHEvtjrMBgdhoI0JpwjgTaRAAYvIjTdBYWSwmI8I+Ei3Roo0H5siaBLElyPKBNeUGwfBQSIbA6KErU9SgMwRE4DkjTwOgxHyJERrbmgoTRryCYJDo6FBCkUY8rG7wKkGpS+P43T-EBIFgWMoAMdgJFwQhdKUVhoCsZB7GceyaD4c8jQAHSBicCRmUM0ioqIJKgA5JAuVqZnifKfKwISuZme2ACq0BwNgZjMpR1H-EAA)

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution, quite simple and a short one. Define Languages as enum.

```
export enum Languages {
    'de-CH',
    'en-GB'
}

export type Language = keyof typeof Languages;
// Language as a key of enum, ie 'de-CH' | 'en-GB'

export type Configuration = {
    languages: Language[],
    defaultLanguage: Language
}

// Results in
export const goodConfig: Configuration = {
    languages: ['de-CH', 'en-GB'],
    defaultLanguage: 'de-CH'
}

export const badConfig: Configuration = {
    languages: ['de-CH', 'en-GB'],
    defaultLanguage: 'de-DE' // <- type error
}
```

And in case you require enum as array, you can easily convert it via following function

```
export function EnumKeys<T>(obj: T): Array<keyof T> {
    return (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>).filter(value => isNaN(Number(value)) !== false);
}
```